# how to insert video path, video name in mysql database in php.?

Tags: php, upload

I want to store video path and name in MySQL database but actually only stored the some fields information which i used in the form. and video stored the test upload folder

I have tried but video path(location) and name not store in database.

Here my code,

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

Controller:

public function Insert_vedio()
{

```
$vedio_data=array(
 'title'=>$this->input->post('Title'),
 'v_name'=>$this->input->post('fileName'), 
 );
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
```

}

Comment: So which part of this code you have currently shown, is supposed to handle the insertion of data into the database? I don’t see _anything_ like that here.

Comment: What did you expect to get from `$this->input->post('Title')` and `$this->input->post('fileName')`? The form you have shown does not have a field named `Title`, and it does not have a field named `fileName` either.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have not mention Title and name in view part. Here My actual code. name is video file name, but don't understand how to give the vedio name.

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="e1"> Title</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Movie Tile" name="Title" id="e1" class="form-control">

     <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br><br>
     <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
     <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
     <h6 id="status" style="color:red"></h6> 
     <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>

    <div class="osahan-area text-center mt-3">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary">Save Changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my Javascript

```
<script>
function _(el)
{
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];

    if(typeof file === "undefined") {

        _("status").innerHTML = "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button";
        _("progressBar").value = 0;
        return;
    }

    $.get('Upload_vedio/Insert_vedio?getsize', function(sizelimit) {
        if(file.type !== "video/mp4") {
            var typewarn = "ERROR: You have to select a MP4-File";
            _("status").innerHTML = typewarn;
            _("progressBar").value = 0;
            return;
        }
        if(sizelimit < file.size) {
            var sizewarn = "ERROR: The File is too big! The maximum file size is ";
            sizewarn += sizelimit/(1024*1024);
            sizewarn += "MB";
            _("status").innerHTML = sizewarn;
            _("progressBar").value = 0;
            return;
        }
        var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("file1", file);
            formdata.append("size", file.size);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "Upload_vedio/Insert_vedio");
            ajax.send(formdata);
    });
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
```